# UNUserNotificationCenter didReceive / willPresent not triggered ios 11

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I have a working application with notifications that appear well. Now I would like to handle some event on notification like when the user tap on the banner.

My iOS Deployment Target is 11.0 and the same for my deployment target.

I implemented everything in my AppDelegate.swift file:

```
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
  var didFinishLaunching: Bool = false

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    let bridge = RCTBridge(delegate: self, launchOptions: launchOptions)
    let rootView = RCTRootView(bridge: bridge, moduleName: "root", initialProperties: nil)
    rootView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1)

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let rootViewController = UIViewController()
    rootViewController.view = rootView
    self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    didFinishLaunching = true

    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

    FirebaseApp.configure()


    // This block is necessary to ask user authorization to receive notification
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
      center.delegate = self
      center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: {(grant, error)  in
        if error == nil {
          if grant {
            print("### permission granted")
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
          } else {
            //User didn't grant permission
          }
        } else {
          print("error: ",error)
        }
      })
    } else {
      // Fallback on earlier versions
      let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    }

    self.firstLaunchAction()
    self.initTracker()

    RNSplashScreen.showSplash("LaunchScreen", inRootView: rootViewController.view)

    return true
  }



  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
      return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
    }
    let token = tokenParts.joined()
    print("### Device Token: \(token)")
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("### Failed to register for remote notifications with error: \(error)")
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            if response.actionIdentifier == "like" {
                  print("### Handle like action identifier")
              } else if response.actionIdentifier == "save" {
                  print("### Handle save action identifier")
              } else {
                  print("### No custom action identifiers chosen")
              }
            // Make sure completionHandler method is at the bottom of this func
            completionHandler()
        }
```

As you can see, I use Firebase to send remote notification so I have a payload in json like this :

```
return {
        notification: {
            title,
            body
        },
        data: {
            title,
            body,
            ...data
        },
        android: {
            ttl: 3600 * 1000,
            notification: {
                icon: 'stock_ticker_update',
                color: '#002559'
            }
        },
        apns: {
            payload: {
                aps: {
                    alert: {
                        title: 'NITL ACUMEN BI RFS CODA Dev Offshore',
                        body: 'Send a Message - PN testing group'
                    },
                    sound: 'default'
                }
            }
        },
        condition
    };
```

Most part of my code is copied from website. But my actual behaviour is that, when I click on the notification banner nothing happen ...

I see the nofication banner so I think there is no problem with my APNs registration. I don't know why **didReceive** is not trigger on click event.

Do I miss something in my implementation ? My notification payload is wrong ?

Does someone can help me to figure out where is my mistake ? I've read an infinite number of tutorials without results. Some help would be really appreciated thank you :)

Comment: Can you try two thing and tell me the results?

1 - Ignore actions, just present a `UIAlertController` on `rootViewController` in `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)`

2 - Can you use tool like `Pusher` or `Knuff` for sending push notification rather than Firebase just for the sake of testing. It will send a much simpler payload.

Let me know the results of this.

Comment: Also talking about actions, are you missing notification action registration step? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/declaring_your_actionable_notification_types

Comment: According to your link, do I need action registration ? I just want to handle the click on a notification. 
I've put an `UIAlertController inside the func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)` and nothing show up. I'm trying to configure Knuff to send notification without Firebase atm

Comment: Try using Knuff, keep app running and DO NOT quit app, just put in background, put dubber inside this function and try clicking on notification. Let me know if debugger point is reached.

Comment: Ok I will try to install Dubber too, it can be long I'm not really familiar with iOS environment

Comment: did it work? Did you find what was the problem?

Comment: No it doesn't works. I've tried to send notification through PushNotifications software cause Knuff doesn't allow to use Authentication Token APNs ... 
The `didReceiveRemoteNotification`method triggers but the `didReceive` still do nothing even when I click on the notification's banner.

Comment: can you upload your test project (I assume it is a test project) to github and share the repo?

Comment: Actually it's a private project ... I figure out the problem cause. It's when my rootViewController is mounted to bind my Javascript bundle because this project use React-Native. If I comment `rootViewController.view = rootView` everything works fine. So I think I have a problem with Javascript part ...

Answer (score 0):

To support a background update notification, make sure that the payload’s `aps` dictionary includes the `content-available` key with a value of 1.

```
{
   "aps" : {
       "content-available" : 1,
       "sound" : “default"
       ....
   },
   ....
}
```

When a background update notification is delivered to the user’s device, iOS wakes up your app in the background and gives it up to 30 seconds to run. In iOS, the system delivers background update notifications by calling the `application: didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler:` method of your app delegate.

Reference: [Creating the Remote Notification Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've already seen this and I've tried it also. I've read **content-available** key turns the remote notification into a silent remote notification. Could you explain me what is the difference and why "simple" remote notification doesn't trigger **didReceive**. method ? I would like to handle only click event